# Spring Cloud Config and Spring Cloud Vault order of initialization

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-vault-config

We are leveraging Spring Cloud Config and Spring Cloud Config Vault. We would like to know if there is a way to "bootstrap the bootstrap", ie we want spring cloud config server to be hit and then pull properties from that to leverage in our vault configuration. We looked at order, but it didn't appear to work, and I assume it is because of the post processing order, but I was hoping I might be missing something.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? Do you want to fetch from Spring Cloud Config e.g. the hostname of the Vault server? Or do you want to load complementary properties?

Comment: I want to fetch host, scheme, and port from config server to drive the connection to vault using spring cloud config vault (so it’s all in bootstrap.yml)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### TL;DR

It doesn't work.

### Explanation

What Spring Cloud does with its bootstrap context, is setting up an application context that contains a set of `PropertySource`s initialized from Spring beans. The bootstrap context is used then as parent context for the actual context created by Spring Boot. A property lookup looks for properties in its own context and within the parent context.

Configuration properties are initialized very early in the startup process and they use properties from the current `Environment`. At the time `ConfigurationProperties` beans are initialized, the `Environment` does not yet contain any remote `PropertySource`s.

The only option I see here (except creating a bootstrap-bootstrap-context) is using the Spring Cloud Config client within your `main` class and contribute Vault properties before any Spring context is built.

Comment: Thank you for confirming what we assumed. It is appreciated as always, the entire spring team rocks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can, but it requires `PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration#initialize()` method overriding. You can't disable bean `PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration`, but you can disable it's initialize method by using `applicationContext.getBeanFactory().getBean(PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.class).setPropertySourceLocators(new ArrayList<>())` in `CustomPropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration` (to avoid obsolete external property sources calls).
In your `CustomPropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration#initialize` method you can retrieve properties from config-server and then customize your `vaultPropertySourceLocator` by inserting generated in config-server secretId of token. 
Don't forget to add your `CustomPropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration` to spring.factories.

So, it's not easy but it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

We created the custom datasource using EnvironmentPostProcessor which will get called before autoconfigure beans
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.application.customize-the-environment-or-application-context

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30049506)