# spring bean override with custom implementation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-bean

I want to override a spring implantation and use my own bean. For example CompositeEnvironmentRepository which is a spring bean, i want to write my own. One way is to delete this bean from the spring jar file and provide my own jar file with my custom bean. Is there any better way to do this. Please suggest.

```
spring:
  application:
    name: spring-cloud-server
  profiles:
    active: vault,git
  cloud:
    vault:
      authentication: CERT
    config:
      server:
        failOnCompositeError: false
        vault:
          host: hostname
          port: 490
          scheme: https
          backend: secret
          defaultKey: 
          kvVersion: 2
          order: 2
          skipSslValidation: false
          authentication: CERT
        git:
          uri: repo-url
          order: 1
          skip-ssl-validation: false
          force-pull: true
          repos:
              dev: 
                pattern:
                - '*/dev'
                uri: url
                searchPaths: '${somepath}'
```

Comment: There should never be a need to delete a class out of a provided Jar. The whole reason we use OOP is so we can override existing code with our own.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation describes how to provide your own environment repository. You probably don't want to override the entire `CompositeEnvironmentRepository`, but create your own `EnvironmentRepository` that provides the specific properties you need. Spring will include yours as part of the "composite".

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html#_custom_composite_environment_repositories

Comment: Issue is , we are not using composite but not sure why it is getting initialized and used. We are using git, vault and requests are going to both and vault request are failing. We dont know how to enforce some requests to GIT and some to vault.

Comment: Then I think you should be able to solve this with config. Can you post your config and any classes with `@Configuration` or `@EnableConfigServer` annotations?

Comment: I have added the yaml  config with my questions.

Comment: You might want to check your versions, as recommended here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42169804/how-to-use-spring-cloud-config-with-a-git-and-vault-composite-environment-reposi